# Unable to import module - Lambda handler Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I am trying to run my python code in lambda passing the handler to the function.module getting the below error, any suggestions how i could resolve this?

the below file test_client_visitor is triggered to call the client_visitor and send an email to the clients accordingly, when i run thd python file test_client_visitor in my local i get the email triggered successfully but in lambda facing the issue.

**file_name: test_client_visitor**

```
function = __import__('client_visitor')
handler = function.scan_clients


class TestFunction(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_function(self):
        file = open('event.json', 'rb')
        try:
            ba = bytearray(file.read())
            event = jsonpickle.decode(ba)
            print('## EVENT')
            print(jsonpickle.encode(event))
            context = {'requestid': '1234'}
            result = handler(event, context)
            print(result)
            self.assertTrue(result, 'Emails could not be sent!')
        finally:
            file.close()
        file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**file_name: client_visitor.py**

```
import datetime

import boto3
from aws_ses import send_bulk_templated_email

# boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore', level='DEBUG')
from mongodb import get_mongo_db


def process_clients(clients, developers, clients_to_be_notified, days):
    if not clients:
        pass

    check_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days)
    for client in clients:
        client_id_ = client['client_id']
        if 'developer_id' in client:
            developers[client_id_] = client['developer_id']
        else:
            if 'secrets' in client:
                secrets = client['secrets']
                for secret in secrets:
                    if 'not_on_or_after' in secret and secret['not_on_or_after'] < check_date.timestamp():
                        clients_to_be_notified.append({'client_id': client_id_,
                                                       'expiration_date': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                                                           secret['not_on_or_after']).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')})
                        print("adding client to notify List", client_id_, ":", client['sort'])


def notify_clients(clients_to_be_notified, developers):
    developer_id_list = []
    for client_secret in clients_to_be_notified:
        developer_id_list.append(developers[client_secret['client_id']])
    if developer_id_list:
        db = get_mongo_db()
        if db:
            users = list(db.users.find({'guid': {'$in': developer_id_list}}, {'email', 'guid'}))
            need_to_send_email = False
            for user in users:
                for client_secret in clients_to_be_notified:
                    if developers[client_secret['client_id']] == user['guid']:
                        client_secret['email'] = user['email']
                        need_to_send_email = True
                        break
            if need_to_send_email:
                return send_bulk_templated_email(clients_to_be_notified)
        else:
            return False
    return True


def scan_clients(event, context):
    local = False
    if 'local' in event:
        local = event['local'] == 'True'
    if local:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
    else:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    days = 30
    if 'days' in event:
        days = int(event['days'])

    print(f"Scanning Clients with {days} or less to secret expiration")

    table = dynamodb.Table('****')
    scan_kwargs = {
        'ProjectionExpression': 'client_id, sort, developer_id, secrets, approved'
    }
    test = False
    if 'test' in event:
        test = event['test'] == 'True'

    done = False
    start_key = None

    developers = {}
    clients_to_be_notified = []
    if test:
        developers['idm-portal1'] = '***'
        clients_to_be_notified = [{'client_id': 'idm-portal1', 'expiration_date': '04/17/2021'}]
    while not done:
        if start_key:
            scan_kwargs['ExclusiveStartKey'] = start_key
        response = table.scan(**scan_kwargs)
        process_clients(response.get('Items', []), developers, clients_to_be_notified, days)
        start_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None)
        done = start_key is None
    print("total developers ", len(developers), " total clients_to_be_notified ", len(clients_to_be_notified))
    return notify_clients(clients_to_be_notified, developers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scan_clients(event={'days': 30, 'local': False, 'test': True}, context=None)
```

**Response**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'test_client_visitor': No module named 'test_client_visitor'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Sırrı Kırımlıoğlu  Updated the code in the above description, and i face the issue only when trying to trigger in lambda. In my local i am able to successfully generate email. Not sure if i am using the right handler format for lambda

Comment: *"getting the below error"* What error?

Comment: The error message is looking for "testclientvisitor". not "test_client_visitor".  Did you register the wrong name somewhere?

Comment: Enzo Tim Roberts This is the error
```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'test_client_visitor': No module named 'test_client_visitor'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Answer (score 0):

Your file must be named `test_client_visitor.py`. The way lambda runs the code is by trying to import the main file and call the handler function. See the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) to set up a handler for Python.

The reason you didn't run into this issue locally is because I assume you are calling python directly on the command line — `python test_client_visitor`. When you import a module in Python, the file has to end in the `.py` extension.

Comment: Ali Samji  My file name was test_client_visitor.py sorry I should have mentioned complete file name in the description, but my file did have the .py extension.

Comment: And you are sure that file is located directly under the root directory of your function — no intermediate directories.

Comment: Ali Samji yes, no intermediate directories

Answer (score 0):

Able to fix this issue with right packaging of the contents to zip, avoided the creation of extra folder with the below command.

Command:

cd folder; zip -r ../filename.zip *

Thankyou everyone for your inputs.